# A problem with eps figure

Tags: ieeetran, eps

I caused a problem when writing an IEEE paper with latex, I use the IEEEtran.cls. 
When I run the latex with "latex"-->"dvi-pdf", it works well. 
However, if I run the latex with "dvi-ps"-->"ps-pdf", it has problems displaying those figures, many figures are blank.

And, my tutor told me that journals generate ps file first and then to pdf most of the time.
So, I don't know how to solve this problem.

The eps figures are generated by Matlab directly.

The Matlab code to save the eps:

```
mkdir figure
savepath = [pwd,'\figure\'];
set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto');
saveas(gcf, [savepath,'fig1','.eps'], 'psc2')
```

The Latex code to include the eps:

```
\begin{figure}[tb!]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=78mm]{fig1.eps}}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

An example of the eps figure is here:
http://www.filedropper.com/fig-gain-alias

An example of the latex:
http://www.filedropper.com/test_165

Comment: We will need more information. Not everyone have access to Matlab. Can you post one of those eps files online and give us a link. Also complete your mwe, it is a lot easier to help if we have a full minimal example, not just a sniplet.

Comment: Also update the code with something others can just copy and test as is without having to add anything. I cannot test today, not at pc

Answer (score 1):

This minimal example works perfectly fine on my system. So the code is OK, as are the eps-files. I can only assume, that maybe your conversion programs do not work correctly. You need to call DviPs, followed by Ghostscripts ps2pdf.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt, final] {IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb!]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=78mm]{fig1.eps}}
    \caption{Test.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb!]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=78mm]{fig-gain-Alias.eps}}
    \caption{Test.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]